# Error: the type name begintransaction does not exist in fragmentmanager in Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm trying to add a new transaction but I get the following error:

```
The type name beginTransaction does not exist in FragmentManager
```

Here is my code:

```
mbtnPhone.Click +=(object sender, EventArgs args)=>{

    FragmentTransaction transaction = new FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
    dialog dialogePhone = new dialog();
    dialogePhone.Show(transaction,"dialogue fragment");
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FragmentManager` is a property on an Activity, you do not instantiate it, remove the `new` keyword:

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
```